# Can I write a text character to vector shape in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to position Korean characters based on their position in the word, to do that, I need to position them based on exactly where the pixels of the character starts, but I don't want to lose the ability to scale the characters.

Using `TextField.textHeight` and whatnot isn't accurate enough for what I'm doing, and writing to BitmapData isn't good enough since I lose the ability to scale crisply.

That said, can I write a letter right into a Shape object? So I would have a vector character object? That way I could position the characters while ignoring the white space all around the character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Posterity:

I ended up writing the characters in Flash IDE, then CTRL-B "breaking" them down. Then exporting each shape as an ActionScript class into a SWC for use in my project in FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [FTE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS9dd7ed846a005b294b857bfa122bd808ea6-8000.html)? Flash Text Engine should help you to work with Korean characters with nice precision and great set of helpful methods.

> The Adobe® Flash® Text Engine (FTE), available starting with Flash Player 10 and Adobe® AIR™1.5, provides low-level support for sophisticated control of text metrics, formatting, and bi-directional text. It offers improved text flow and enhanced language support. While it can be used to create and manage simple text elements, the FTE is primarily designed as a foundation for developers to create text-handling components. As such, Flash Text Engine assumes a more advanced level of programming expertise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it wasn't tight enough for what I needed so I decided to export shapes of the characters from Flash IDE.